# Overloading error in C++ [Pass by Value and Pass by Reference]

Tags: c++, overloading, pass-by-reference, pass-by-value

I'm working on a project that calculate income for both type of employees (salaried and hourly) using overloading.This project has 3 files, here is the main source:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Grosspay.h"
using namespace std;

void Grosspay::determineGrosspay()
{
    cout << "Enter 1 - Calculate payroll for hourly employee" << endl;
    cout << "Enter 2 - Calculate payroll for salary employee" << endl;
    cout << "Enter 3 - Exit" << endl;

    cout << "Federal Tax is 10% of Grosspay" << endl;
    cout << "State Tax is 5% of Grosspay" << endl;
    while (choice != 3)
    {
        cout << "\nEnter your choice: " << endl;
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            cout << "Enter employee ID: " << endl;
            cin >> ID;
            cout << "Enter hours: " << endl;
            cin >> hours;
            cout << "Enter payrate: " << endl;
            cin >> payrate;

            cout << "Employee ID: %d" << ID << endl;
            cout << "The net pay for hourly employee: %.2f\n" << income(hours, payrate) << endl;
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "Enter employee ID: " << endl;
            cin >> ID;
            cout << "Enter salary: " << endl;
            cin >> year;

            cout << "The net pay for salaried employee: %.2f\n" << income(year) << endl;
            break;
        case 3:
            cout << "Exited program" << endl;
            break;
        default:
            cout << "Please try again!" << endl;
            break;
        }
    }
}
double income(double hours, double payrate)
{
    double grosspay = 0;
    double federaltax = .10;
    double statetax = .05;
    double totaltax;
    double netpay;
    if (hours <= 40)
    {
        grosspay = payrate * hours;
    }if (hours > 40 && hours <= 50)
    {
        grosspay = (payrate * 40) + ((hours - 40) * payrate * 1.5);
    }
    if (hours > 50)
    {
        grosspay = (payrate * 40) + (10 * payrate * 1.5) + ((hours - 50) * payrate * 2);
    }
    cout << "Grosspay weekly is %.2f\n" << grosspay << endl;

    federaltax = grosspay * .10;
    cout << "Federal Tax is: %.2f\n" << federaltax << endl;

    statetax = grosspay * .05;
    cout << "State Tax is: %.2f\n" << statetax << endl;

    totaltax = federaltax + statetax;
    cout << "Total tax is: %.2f\n" << totaltax << endl;

    netpay = grosspay - totaltax;
    return (netpay);

}
double income(double year)
{
    double grosspay;
    double federaltax = .10;
    double statetax = .05;
    double totaltax;
    double netpay;

    grosspay = year / 52;
    cout << "Grosspay weekly is %.2f\n" << grosspay << endl;

    federaltax = grosspay * .10;
    cout << "Federal Tax is: %.2f\n" << federaltax << endl;

    statetax = grosspay * .05;
    cout << "State Tax is: %.2f\n" << statetax << endl;

    totaltax = federaltax + statetax;
    cout << "Total Tax is: %.2f\n" << totaltax << endl;

    netpay = grosspay - totaltax;
    return (netpay);
}
```

I do not know why the program couldn't find the **income**
from

```
cout << "The net pay for hourly employee: %.2f\n" << income(hours, payrate) << endl;
cout << "The net pay for salaried employee: %.2f\n" << income(year) << endl;
```

Also, I need to use at least one of the functions in program to demonstrate pass-by-value; and at least, one of the functions to demonstrate pass-by-reference with reference arguments. I have no ideas how to put it in the source. Any one please help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the `income` functions are not defined within the `Grosspay` class, they should be defined before they're called. Try moving the definitions of `income` before the `determineGrosspay` method.

An alternative solution is to use a [function prototype](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_prototype) by moving the prototype "before" the `determineGrosspay` function and it's implementation after.

---

Since you asked about pass by reference and pass by value in the comments, I'll include it in this answer. What you've written for the `income` functions is pass-by-value. This means a copy of the variable(s) is/are passed to the function.

Passing by reference means you pass a reference of the variable to the function rather than a copy of it. Pass by reference assumes the following function signature for your application: `income(const double &year)` if you do not want to modify the year variable within the function, and `income(double &year)` if you want to modify the value of `year`.

---

Use `double income(const double &year)` for your application.

Please study what this means because it's an important part of the language.

Comment: This actually solved my problem. Thank you  very much. Do you have any ideas how to do pass by value and pass by reference for this project?

Comment: I'm really understand much what you said about pass by reference. Sorry because I'm a beginner. What should I do to change one of the function to pass by reference? `double income(double& year)`

Comment: `double income(const double &year)`

Is that all I have to change from my code? Do I have to change anything inside the function? Because in the book examples, it seems a lot harder than this!

Comment: I looked at your code and it looks like that's all you have to change. Nothing within the function needs to change. Compile it with my function signature and ensure that you get the same result.

Comment: Okay, Thank you very much! You are really nice that explained carefully.

Comment: No worries mate. Just return the favor in the future.